# Accessing Rpi via android browser - url: <hostname>.local

Tags: raspberry-pi

I've been working on web based project for home automation. And recently I've installed

```
apt-get install avahi-daemon
```

so that apart from typing the ip address, I can type (hostname).local in my browser - works fine in PC.

I've tried to do the same on android mobile, but it doesn't happens and it takes that input string as an search string for default search engine. How to solve it?